# High performance pixel manipulation in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing

I am new trying out a high-speed image display in HTML5/JS. I am fairly new to HTML5/JS and is trying to evaluate options available for rendering images on to screen.

Input is an array of pixels.

I played around with  CanvasRenderingContext2D, and used a canvas and putImageData to render pixels onto screen, but I ended up with slower FPS with increase in image size. The use case I want to address is rendering raw pixel arrays onto screen, and not drawing shapes/drawings. My target is to render at the highest possible FPS.

```
        var imageCanvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
        var imageContext = imageCanvas.getContext('2d', { alpha: false });
        var pixelData = imageContext.createImageData(imageWidth, imageWidth);
        // ---------------------------------------------------------
        // here: Fill up pixelData with image pixels to be rendered
        // ---------------------------------------------------------
        imageContext.putImageData(pixelData , 0, 0);
```

1. For such an use-case, how should I proceed? I read at many places putImageData is the bottleneck here, and a better way would be to use DrawImage. Is it possible to avoid using putImageData and use DrawImage to read from pixelData and render?
2. How efficiently can I use GPU?
3. Does WebGLRenderingContext suit this scenario?

Comment: is that the whole code? lots of bolierplate for one putImageData() call...

Comment: Sorry about it, Can I render in a more efficient way?

Comment: ideally, you would want to call only `putImageData` each time

Comment: Yes, true. I am doing the same.. the rest of the code are like init, and the putImageData runs for multiple iterations with different set of pixels

Answer (score 0):

For high performance graphics on html canvas.
There's only one way to do .
Its by making use of webgl provided by glES.

using core opengl could be annoying so you may want to use some libraries like [Three.js](https://threejs.org) or [pixijs](https://www.pixijs.com/)